# How to include failed matches values in cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to return a value for every population whether the population is connected to the node or not. if there is no connection between population and allele it should just return a NULL

I tried to use optional match but this just returns all the connected nodes and no values for the not connected nodes.

This is my current attempt at achieving it:

```
MATCH (p:Population)
with p
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)<-[s:has_support]-(a:Allele)
RETURN a, count(p.name) limit 25
```

I used count as a quick check if it always returns the right amount of values, it should always return the same amount of values as population nodes in the graph database.

How do i achieve this?

Kind regard,
julian

Answer (score 1):

I have found the issue, `collect` and `count` ignore null values. To solve it I used the COALESCE function to set null to 0.

```
MATCH (p:Population) match (a:Allele)
with a, p
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[s:has_support]->(p)
return a, collect(COALESCE(s.value, 0)), collect(p.name) limit 25
```